# External monitor causes very high CPU usage

Tags: macos, display, screen, performance, cpu

I have an external LG 27UD69P-W monitor connected (via HDMI) to my late 2013 MacBook Pro, which causes the CPU usage of the Mac to go extremely high (`kernel_task` > 400%, sometimes much higher even), with the fan running very fast. (The computer is so sluggish that even the cursor does not move smoothly, often.)

Some things I've noted:

- SMC reset doesn't help.
- Safe mode doesn't help.
- GPU usage is very low (almost zero) when monitor is connected. Is this to be expected?
- Occasionally I can connect the monitor and still have a usable computer (< 50% CPU usage) for 5 or 10 minutes, but that's it.
- Monitor works fine with another MacBook.

What could be the issue here? A troublesome kext perhaps? Any suggestions?

### Update

Here's my [system log](https://gist.github.com/cf5ea6c2f37501be246375c04b11089a) for when I plug in the screen and a couple of minutes after, while the computer is running sluggish / high CPU usage. Notable are the following sorts of events:

- `kernel   Currently unsupported feature requested`
- `kernel   DisplayPipe Capabilities are not supported on offline Fbs`
- `IOAudioStream`
- `IOAudioEngineUserClient`
- `streamFormat`
- `coreaudiod`*
- `OSCMultiMonitor`
- `tccd`
- `coreduetd`*
- `com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent  Invalid display 0x1b5671a5`

Here's a ["normal" system log](https://gist.github.com/6f841e2ea881c7ef2d57e9134109a2f9) for a few minutes while the monitor is *not* plugged in.

Comment: is that a new problem? did it work before

Comment: @Buscar웃 Same issue since the day I got it...

Comment: take look in the Console log to see what are those 2 doing

Comment: also just try to scale down the resolution for test purpose

Answer (score 2):

There has been some unconfirmed reports that the NVIDA drivers that came with High Sierra are not operating correctly.

Suggestion is to get updated Drivers from NVIDA directly.

Some have suggested to change the resolution back and fore to fix the problem.

It also looks like your system is no doing Graphics switching.

Check in System Preference that the Auto Graphic switching is turned on.

*Also it could be very useful to us if you copy/paste some 30-50 lines in from your Console at the time when you plug in the external monitor so we can see what is going on.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestions. My NVIDIA card is NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, and I don't see an option for macOS on the driver download page. Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, but no macOS! https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk

Comment: I've tried with with graphics switching on and off; same problem. Here's the log for around the time I plug in the monitor for a few minutes after. (Interestingly this time it wasn't so bad... I got video to play reasonably, albeit a bit choppy. GPU usage was very low again, but kernel_task wasn't too high.) Here's a few 100 lines of logs after I plug it in: https://gist.github.com/alexreg/b03863cb375b924fe211600aa25fe1fb

Comment: check this out https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/125379/en-us

Comment: Thanks, do I need to restart after?

Comment: Ah... "Mac OS X version 10.13.6 (17G65) is not supported with this package. Please see NVIDIA’s website for further driver information."

Comment: OK, your CPU (kernel) gets flooded with IOAudio problems

Comment: @Noldorin sorry, they only made it up to 10.13.1 :(

Comment: Oh I see. Is that from the external monitor, or something else? Maybe the "Boom 3D" software I have installed?

Comment: Also I found https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/130460/en-us, which is good.

Comment: you also have a website that consumes a lot of CPU, close it for now.

Comment: Yeah probably the website playing the video while I was testing.

Comment: Okay, I followed <https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025945/mac-cuda-driver-fully-compatible-with-macos-high-sierra-10-13-error-quot-update-required-quot-solved-/> and installed the latest "web" & CUDA drivers <https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/136062/en-us> and <https://www.nvidia.com/object/macosx-cuda-396.148-driver.html>. It's not quite as bad as it was before, but still not great. Do you think the IOAudio thing could still be the problem? Any other ideas?

Comment: yes the IOAudio keeps your CPU bussy

Comment: How can I find put where it’s coming from though?

Comment: Lets do that as separate question, getting the "Please avoid extended discussions in comments".

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the question, so maybe you could just add another answer now? :-)

Answer (score 2):

In reply to your updated and extended question

There is a problem with your Boom 3D

```
error 18:09:59.938200 +0100 Boom 3D AUBase.cpp:804:DispatchSetProperty: ca_require: inDataSize == sizeof(UInt32) InvalidPropertyValue
```

That probably leads to the continuous and repeating Coreaudiod and IOAudio

I do not know how to fix it, see [Boom 3D support](https://forum.globaldelight.com/index.php?p=/categories/boom-2-discussions)

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. Unfortunately even uninstall Boom 3D completely doesn't seem to help... could anything else be causing the issue?

Comment: Any thoughts? :-)

Comment: @Noldorin do you still have the Boom showing in the log ? and turn off all your sharing for now.

Comment: ok, so you have Alfred 3 installed, and also have some USB audio connected ?

Comment: Yes to Alfred 3, no to USB audio, as I understand.

Comment: Here's my updated system log, with Boom 3D uninstalled, NVidia web & CUDA drivers installed: https://gist.github.com/alexreg/f8a65a0e6ce84670b4ff5fb3daeda296

Comment: so you have Boom 3D, Alfred, Bartender and who knows what else ! just start the system without all that crap (Safe mode) Start or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key...And report is the Monitor working now ??

Comment: Yeah, tried that, no luck sadly...

Comment: sadly I have to give up at this time....maybe someone else can help you

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your help anyway! Can't say you didn't try. I have a suspicion it may be a hardware thing in fact...

Comment: it could be, but what I see you have a lots of crap running, overloading the CPU and RAM, if I might suggest, turn off all Web browsers and all 3d party stuff, so the OS X has a chance.

Comment: Given it happened on safe mode with nothing open still, not likely. Also, my MBP runs smoothly normally with everything open!

Comment: that was for me, to be able to read the console report